# {"msg":"Fence: onClientEventRegionState, invalid state", "regionState":"0"} in ios

Tags: ios, swift, ios10

I want to notify the user when he/she reached to a particular floor by using estimote beacons. To do my task I developed my code like below:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    self.beaconManager.delegate = self

    self.beaconManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
    let firstFloorRegion = CLBeaconRegion(
        proximityUUID: uuid,
        major: 2, identifier: "")
    firstFloorRegion.notifyOnEntry = true
    firstFloorRegion.notifyOnExit = true
    firstFloorRegion.notifyEntryStateOnDisplay = true
    self.beaconManager.startMonitoring(for: firstFloorRegion)
    self.beaconManager.requestState(for: firstFloorRegion)

    return true
}
func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didDetermineState region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    NSLog("didDetermineState Called")
}
private func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didEnterRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    NSLog("DidEnterRegion Called")
}
private func beaconManager(manager: AnyObject, didExitRegion region: CLBeaconRegion) {

    NSLog("didExitRegion Called")
}
```

for a few days it worked perfectly. But from last 2 days onwards its showing the error in xcode console like this:

> **[Client] {"msg":"Fence: onClientEventRegionState, invalid state", "regionState":"0"}**.

I can't understand what it means. I didn't find any solution in internet also. Help me to get out of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have noticed iBeacon monitoring (and region monitoring in general) takes up to 10 minutes to work after a phone restart. Sure enough, I restarted my phone and got your error in the console output when I called

```
manager.requestState(for: myRegion)
```

I have never seen Apple talk about any negative effects of calling

```
manager.startMonitoring(for: myRegion)
```

on an already registered region. However, I do not call this every time the app launches. Instead, I check monitored regions like this:

```
for monitoredRegion in self.locationManager.monitoredRegions as! Set<CLBeaconRegion> {

   print("Monitoring: " + monitoredRegion.proximityUUID.uuidString + " " + monitoredRegion.identifier)

   self.locationManager.requestState(for: monitoredRegion)

   switch monitoredRegion.proximityUUID.uuidString {
      case myRegionUUID.uuidString:
         needToMonitorMyRegion = false
      default:
         break
    }
}
```

I do not get the error when I validate registration like this. I only ge the error on phone restart.